# Keyboard navigation support on Twitter

Tags: twitter, keyboard-shortcuts

Does Twitter have support for keyboard navigation?

I've managed to guess <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> for going up and down tweets, but I don't know any others. Are there keys for actions like refreshing tweets (not <kbd>F5</kbd>), following someone, focusing the search bar, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hit <kbd>?</kbd> for a list of those shortcuts available in twitter.com.

Comment: Yes and what exactly do you hit to turn off this shortcut menu from showing when you just want to use a question mark?

Comment: `Esc` I imagine. What you've left here is not an answer; it should have been a comment on [phwd' answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/10482/354).