# Disable twitter's keyboard shortcut

Tags: twitter, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, mac

For the simple reason sometimes I want to search the timeline using <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and when I try it some shortcut will be activated and I'll be *moved away* from the timeline after having loaded many pages of it. Really, really annoying stuff!

So, how can we disable [it](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10481/keyboard-navigation-support-on-twitter/10482#10482) **without** moving back to the old interface? Is there any way? Though I do use Safari some times, a Google Chrome extension or a greasemonkey script would suffice here!

<sup>Funny thing on gmail I like to leave the same feature **on**, but there I can disable it very simply if I wanted to! :-|</sup>

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/168087/how-to-forbid-keyboard-shortcut-stealing-by-websites-in-firefox

Comment: @diyism who uses firefox? argh... might as well use internet explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is for non-windows users I believe. Windows users use `Ctrl` + `F` and it works to open up the find interface. But when you're using a `Command` button with other systems, it seems that it is not registering the `Command`, just the `f` which "favorites" the message. Is that the issue you're having? Here is a [list of the new keyboard shortcuts](http://www.seoservicesgroup.com/blog/2010/09/twitter-introduces-new-keyboard-shorcut-keys/18852/). [image]

There is no way to disable them without going back. But if the problem I mentioned is the correct one, you might try de-activating selection of the current message. Push `Esc` first.

Comment: No, it still looks like a random effect to me. And I doubt it's only to non-windows. Sometimes it doesn't affect, sometimes it does. Lastly, I still hope there is some way to disable (and/or fix) them.

Comment: Do you always use the same browser? If so, which one? Did you try the `Esc` button before `Command` + `F`?

Comment: Ok, I just found out it ain't random, and it's always after I press `Command` + `G` to search again, then back to `Command` + `F` it will just `F` instead **and** pressing `ESC` before that last one will actually "*fix it*". Not a good solution, but it's a solution already!

Answer (score 1):

I clicked <kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> at the same time. It went away when I tried to use to again. Solved my problem.

Comment: Hey Marlene, welcome to stackexchange (I guess)! Sounds like you described exactly what I said in my comment on the other answer. :)